# Homepage Showing a JSON code Instead of Homepage

Tags: magento2

We are using M2.3.5-p1

In the last three days the site home page show text as in the attached image.
After cleaning cache it returns.
This is only in home page

We are using Varnish cache and with Amasty layered navigation module.

```
{"categoryProducts":"","navigation":"","navigationTop":"","breadcrumbs":"","h1":"<div class=\"page-title-wrapper\">\n    <h1 class=\"page-title\"\n                >\n        <span class=\"base\" data-ui-id=\"page-title-wrapper\" >\u05d1\u05d9\u05d5-\u05d2\u05d0\u05d9\u05d4<\/span>    <\/h1>\n    <\/div>\n","title":"\u05d7\u05e0\u05d5\u05ea \u05d8\u05d1\u05e2, \u05d1\u05d9\u05ea \u05de\u05e8\u05e7\u05d7\u05ea, \u05d5\u05d9\u05d8\u05de\u05d9\u05e0\u05d9\u05dd, \u05ea\u05e8\u05d5\u05e4\u05d5\u05ea  | \u05d1\u05d9\u05d5-\u05d2\u05d0\u05d9\u05d4","bottomCmsBlock":"","url":"https:\/\/www.biogaya.co.il\/","productsCount":"0","js_init":"","isDisplayModePage":"","currentCategoryId":"0","currency":"","store":"","store_switcher":"","behaviour":"","categoryData":"<div class=\"category-view\"><\/div>","cmsPageData":""}
```

What can cause this issue?

[image]

Thank you,
Eran Greenwald

Answer (score 0):

You should have someone to check it for you.

The easies solution is to try turning off all third party modules and also theme. See if the stock/origin Magento is working.

The better way to do is to inspect the page, to see where that JSON comes from, but it requires some knowledge, so hiring a new dev is a good choice.